# Kernel panic on boot after fresh install of 16.04

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I had Ubuntu 15.10 running fine on my Thinkpad x200.

The live USB of 16.04 runs fine, ran a check on it's files - checks out ok.

Told the installer to format the ext4 drive and install 16.04 from scratch, everything seemed to go well up till after the restart - got a kernel panic right after the grub screen.

Here's a [Boot-info summary](http://paste2.org/DcvhzvjD).

The error message during panic says /bin/sh exists but can not be executed.

I can execute that sh from the live USB though... (by going to the mount point of sda2, and executing it's /bin/sh)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this problem is associated with an installation of a 64bit Ubuntu using a USB created by unetbootin..

Creating a disk using Linux Live USB creator and installing from it fixed the problem.

I still wonder what was wrong with the init, if someone has any insight regarding this error...